# Creating an Improved Digital Zoom

Tags: language-agnostic, video

Ok, so I have a given video source (for the sake of the example, it is a camera). It does not have optical zoom, but we supply digital zoom instead.  Now this digital zoom is pretty simple, simply cropping the image to a specified portion, and filling the screen with that portion.

The problem is that the zoomed video can have pretty rubbish quality when the digital zoom is enabled.

I am wondering if anyone knows of an approach by which a higher quality of digital zoom can be achieved in real-time.

The software is on Windows, and the video is rendered using DirectShow, but it isn't a platform solution I'm necessarily after, more just a better approach to the problem.

Cheers

Comment: @Kazar: so you found *none* of the responses to be in any way helpful?

Comment: It's not that, I've been busy trying the various suggestions before I select the best answer (and I don't work weekends).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered [two](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/08/the-myth-of-infinite-detail-bilinear-vs-bicubic.html) [posts](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/07/better-image-resizing.html) by Jeff Atwood on this topic. If you want better than bilinear resizing, fractal resizing seems to be a good alternative.

The link Jeff gives to the CodeProject example is dead, but I think he's referring to [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/imgresizoutperfgdiplus.aspx).

Comment: This definitely pushed me down the right path with fractal resizing.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply filters which try to improve the image quality, but there is a definite limit to what you can do. You can't produce information (i.e. image quality) out of thin air.

[The enhance button](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EnhanceButton) does not exist.

There are algorithms that can produce pretty impressive enhancements for *some specific input* (for example there are good solutions for [pixel art](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_art_scaling_algorithms)), but applying those to other kinds of input produces much worse output.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [Google for upscaling of standard def video using ffdshow](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=dvd+upscaling+ffdshow&rls=com.microsoft:en-gb:IE-SearchBox&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=ie7&rlz=1I7HPND&redir_esc=&ei=ClijS8-dKqb20wSO_bjqCQ).  This will show you what algorithms you need to look at to get a reasonable increase in visual quality.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

- use the best interpolation method that you can, e.g. Lanczos
- if you have several consecutive frames with little or no motion between them (e.g. if it's video) then you may be able to combine the frames to get better upsampling for a single frame